# Xamarin.Android -coordinates from SQLite are not drawn on Google maps

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, google-maps, xamarin

I'm trying to implement Google maps markers using C#.I have lat/long values saved into my SQLite db which i then read and want to display on the map.There's an option on the action bar 'Load Points' that should call a method 'ReadPointsFromDb()' where i create the new Markers.i have tried a couple of examples with no difference,although drawing Markers on a map is pretty standard and i think I've done it correctly,except there's no effect when i click on Load points.Nothing changes.No markers are drawn on the map each time.

This is what the method looks like :

```
//retrieve a list of all the contents of receiverpoint table items
    public void ReadPointsFromDb()
    {


        double lat = 0;
        double lon = 0;

        int count = dataManager.GetAllReceiverPoints ().Count;

        foreach(ReceiverPointTable item in dataManager.GetAllReceiverPoints ())
        {
            lat = item.LATITUDE;

            lon = item.LONGITUDE;
        }

        if(map != null){



            RunOnUiThread (new Action (delegate {

                map.Clear ();

                receiver_point = new LatLng (lat, lon);

                var markerOpt1 = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOpt1.SetTitle("Test point");
                markerOpt1.SetPosition (receiver_point);
                markerOpt1.InvokeIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueMagenta));
                map.AddMarker(markerOpt1);
            }));

        }

    }
```

**EDIT 1**
I modified the method above to draw markers inside a foreach loop but i still don't get any changes.Only the marker for the current position is drawn

```
public void ReadPointsFromDb()
    {
        double lat = 0;
        double lon = 0;

        List<LatLng> newPoints = new List<LatLng> ();

        int count = dataManager.GetAllReceiverPoints ().Count;


        IList<ReceiverPointTable> allPoints = dataManager.GetAllReceiverPoints ();

        System.Console.WriteLine ("size of All points : " + count);
try
        {
            if(allPoints.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach(ReceiverPointTable item in allPoints)
                        {
                            lat = item.LATITUDE;

                            lon = item.LONGITUDE;

                            receiver_point = new LatLng(lat,lon);


                            RunOnUiThread (new Action (delegate {

                            map.Clear ();

                            var markerOpt1 = new MarkerOptions();
                            markerOpt1.SetTitle("Your current location");
                            markerOpt1.SetPosition (map_center);
                            markerOpt1.InvokeIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueMagenta));
                            map.AddMarker(markerOpt1);



                            var markerOpt2 = new MarkerOptions();
                            markerOpt2.SetTitle("Test point");
                            markerOpt2.SetPosition (receiver_point);
                            markerOpt2.InvokeIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueRed));
                            map.AddMarker(markerOpt2);



                    }));



                        }
                }

        }catch(Exception e)
            {

            logger.Error (this, e);
            }
}
```

**EDIT 2**
This is how i modified the method again to have a proper sequence of events:
    public void ReadPointsFromDb()
        {

```
 try
        {

                if(map != null)
                {

                    //RunOnUiThread (new Action (delegate { 

                    //map.Clear (); 

                    //}));
foreach(ReceiverPointTable item in dataManager.GetAllReceiverPoints ())
                        {
                            var markerOpt2 = new MarkerOptions();
                            markerOpt2.SetTitle("Test point");
                            markerOpt2.SetPosition (new LatLng(item.LATITUDE,item.LONGITUDE));
                            markerOpt2.InvokeIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueRed));

                            RunOnUiThread (new Action (delegate { 

                            map.AddMarker(markerOpt2); 

                            }));

                        }

            }
        }catch(Exception e)
            {

            logger.Error (this, e);
            }
```

Comment: If you place a log call in `ReadPointsFromDb()`, does it get called? Just making sure that the method is correctly called from your button press event.

Comment: Yes @Koh .I'm writing to the console from inside the ReadPointsFromDb and i can tell when we're inside the method.

Comment: How many markers are you expecting? This piece of code will only print one marker. First make sure that your `foreach` loops through a valid list. If there are items in `dataManager.GetAllReceiverPoints()`, call `map.AddMarker()` on each one.

Comment: i'll need to make some changes in the datamanager class then,and also add the foreach loop to the ReadPointsFromDb and let you know if they get drawn.Shouldn't it add the Marker still,regardless of how many points they are?

Comment: It should add a marker, if there are points in the dataManager. If there are no points, it should add a marker at lat = 0 and lon = 0.

Comment: Okay.I'll add the changes you suggested and see if i get the markers.

Comment: @Koh it still doesn't add a marker to the new points read from the db.It re-draws a marker for the current position,but ignores the rest.I'll add an edit above to show that code.

Comment: I can't see the entire code from my phone, but I see that you call map.clear() in your foreach loop. That will cause all previously made markers to get cleared.

Comment: @Koh i've made another edit,following your advice on the map.clear() part.I still don't get a marker drawn :( It's strange because i can only seem to add a marker on the user's current location but never any other Latlong value.Even if i try to add a marker say in OnCreate(),or elsewhere in the code,it also doesn't draw a marker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to show multiple points on the map from the ReceiverPointTable, I think the problem is within your control /flow logic and the order you are doing things and the map clear function.  Your logic seems to be looping through all the data in your db but then only finding the last ReceiverPointTable item and putting that on the map.

I think better code might be

```
if(map != null)
{
    RunOnUiThread (new Action (delegate { map.Clear (); });

    foreach(ReceiverPointTable item in dataManager.GetAllReceiverPoints ())
    {
        var markerOpt1 = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOpt1.SetTitle("Test point");
        markerOpt1.SetPosition (new LatLng (item.LATITUDE, item.LONGITUDE));
        markerOpt1.InvokeIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(
                                      BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueMagenta));
        RunOnUiThread (new Action (delegate { map.AddMarker(markerOpt1); }));
    }
}
```

**Edit**, so this is a minimum viable code that I have created that iterates over a collection and draws on a map.

Main.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <fragment
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load points" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;

namespace MapTest
{
    [Activity (Label = "MapTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        GoogleMap map;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            MapFragment mapFrag =  FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.map);
            map = mapFrag.Map;
            Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);
            button.Click += delegate {
                LoadPoints();
            };
        }

        void LoadPoints() 
        {
            var points = new List<Tuple<string, double, double>> () {
                Tuple.Create("London", 51.50000, -0.11670),
                Tuple.Create("New York", 40.75170, -73.99420),
                Tuple.Create("Hong Kong", 21.75000, 115.00000),
                Tuple.Create("Berlin", 52.51670, 13.33330),
                Tuple.Create("Buenos Aires", -34.33320, -58.49990),
                Tuple.Create("Cairo, Egypt", 30.00000, 31.28330),
                Tuple.Create("Geneva", 46.23330, 6.06670),
                Tuple.Create("Singapore",  1.36670, 103.75000),
                Tuple.Create("Washington", 38.89750, -77.00920),
                Tuple.Create("Canberra", -35.35000, 149.16670)
            };

            var fiveRandomPointsFromList = points.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(5);

            if (map != null)
            {
                RunOnUiThread (new Action (delegate { map.Clear (); }));

                foreach(var point in fiveRandomPointsFromList)
                {
                    var markerOpt1 = new MarkerOptions()
                        .SetTitle(point.Item1)
                        .SetPosition(new LatLng(point.Item2, point.Item3))
                        .InvokeIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(
                         BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueMagenta));
                    RunOnUiThread (new Action (delegate { map.AddMarker(markerOpt1); }));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work then you know there is something wrong with your build.  If it does work and your previous code fails then you need to debug what values you are getting back from calls from dataManager.GetAllReceiverPoints() and whether this is valid values for Lat Long points.

Comment: i have modified my code to be exactly like you've suggested above, but i still don't get any markers.I honestly don't know what it is i'm missing.I"m also checking the size of the list to make sure it has data.

Comment: Have you got anywhere with this or are you still struggling?

Comment: Let me try and follow your example and see if it works

Comment: So i used your example as it is,and at first i didn't see any change.But i have set my camera to zoom into the current location.i commented that out and had a wider view..then  saw the markers on the above coordinates.Now we know it works.When i substitute them with my coordinates,i don't get markers however.So it's probably my coordinates.

Comment: This finally worked @AlexC.Thank you so much for all your help.I truly appreciate it

Comment: The previous method of implementation of using a foreach loop also worked eventually.I had to zoom out of the current location to view the markers.